# Brand new MacBook Pro flagship behaving strangely

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, performance, cpu, gpu

Today i got the newest available **MacBook Pro** flagship model. After setting up some basics, installing Photoshop, JRE, XAMPP and NetBeans, i started to use the machine a bit, doing some basic coding.

While using Netbeans, the fans rev up in an abnormal fashion. Of course i checked the CPU usage in *Activity Monitor*, but nothing abnormal showed up - merely just 7%-10% usage varying. There was simply nothing running, that would use up the CPU. I have owned a 2014 model previously and it never showed such behaviour. In fact, unless NetBeans was scanning a huge project and the CPU usage went up to 100%+, the fans were not even noticeable at all.

**What i tried**

After some research, i *reset the SMC*, but the issue remained. Instead of working flawlessly, after resetting the SMC and rebooting the machine, then running it for a few minutes and then opening *apple.stackexchange.com* in **Google Chrome**, suddenly the entire screen turned white and the only thing that was still there was the mouse pointer, which i could move around, but otherwise the machine was unresponsive.

I rebooted and checked the log, which under *System Diagnostic Reports* now showed a file prefixed with *Kernel* which said:

```
Event: GPU Reset
Application: WindowServer
OS Version: Mac OS X Version 10.10.3 (Build 14D2134)
Graphics Hardware: AMD Radeon R9 M370X
Signature: 0
```

Followed by a huge chunk of dump data.

Sadness fills my being.

Could this be a hardware issue? Badly applied cooling paste? Would you send it back and buy a new one, or try to get it fixed?

---

Specs:

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), Core i7 2.8 GHz, 16 GB RAM, Intel Iris Pro 1.5 GB + AMD Radeon R9 M370X running Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: Apple doesn't denote a flagship model. Can you list the specific manual and build? Why not reach out to AppleCare to see if they can run diagnostics remotely or have a quick check that your hardware is in spec? Be aware that we're not CS for Apple so try to do the research to explain how CS couldn't solve your problem if this gets closed as off topic or too broad. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y?cb=1

Comment: Sorry, i thought it's clear. I'll add more specs

Comment: Just out of interest can the GPU card be easily switched off ? If so does disabling the GPU card make the problem go away ? If so can you use this to identify incompatible applications ?

Comment: The crashes stopped once i forced integrated graphics at all times. The fan issue improved from there on out. I have returned the machine however, and gotten a brand new one, directly from Apple, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a hardware issue, you'll have CPU usage and issues with a stock OS. Back things up and wipe it. Then run the iLife apps like garage band and iMovie and Photos to soak the CPU.

Everything in my experience is you have some software issues that aren't ready for the new API and new CPU/GPU and will have occasional panics as the drivers get updated for non-apple users or the non-apple code gets patched to behave properly.

- Adobe is notorious for needing a patch for new HW.
- JRE, XAMPP, NetBeans - would depend heavily on your versions
- Apple offer free hardware support - why not get them to check things and let you know. Run `sysdiagnose` each time you get a panic so you have all the diagnostic logs saved if you end up with some pattern of 10 or more KP so that engineering can analyze things. If you have less than a dozen crashes or can't make it happen, realize that you'll likely need to pay someone to analyze those diagnostics as it's time consuming and requires fairly specialized experience to make headway on non-reproducible core dumps and panics.

Comment: Thank you for your input. JRE, XAMPP and Netbeans - all downloaded today at the newest versions. I am considering to go to a service shop tomorrow. We don't have Apple as a store in Austria, unfortunately. This is my 6th MacBook Pro, i never had troubles with them. It pains me to pay 3.600 Euros and get a device that is somewhat faulty.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov Awesome plan. I expect even if you get support online from Apple they will go out of their way to make sure your new Mac works fully or gets exchanged / returned as you wish.